# De-duplicate part of a table on given condition

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group, postgresql-performance

This is my `message` table. Now I am trying to write an query to group records by `collection_id` (only first instance) if `type` `multi-store` else by `message`.`id` .

```
                  id                  |            collection_id             |      type      | affiliation_id |    status    | scheduled_for_date 
--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+----------------+----------------+--------------+--------------------
 1143c066-01ed-4eb5-a146-68487de702a9 | bce85e31-4d2f-43b1-b263-57fca356856f | multi-store    | 12091          | draft        | 
 e1183732-e91d-42eb-9998-110e039cfc25 | bce85e31-4d2f-43b1-b263-57fca356856f | multi-store    | 12092          | draft        | 
 8f962a49-7da1-46d0-87b9-595788767dfe | bce85e31-4d2f-43b1-b263-57fca356856f | multi-store    | 12097          | draft        | 
 6e4dee09-7a4e-47be-bdd8-935a67bb2063 | 740f6b42-bbf1-4aeb-8fe9-6874635d9e29 | multi-store    | 12091          | draft        | 
 79afab0e-14e7-4d1b-9a15-358763743c3e | 740f6b42-bbf1-4aeb-8fe9-6874635d9e29 | multi-store    | 12092          | draft        | 
 7bc78bee-074a-4031-9492-954e7c4eeb09 | 740f6b42-bbf1-4aeb-8fe9-6874635d9e29 | multi-store    | 12097          | draft        | 
 3bb38fbd-d411-4f78-9c42-c858bf57b784 |                                      | standard-store | 10511          | draft        | 
 fbb3b175-1a3b-4515-b0b3-0ce6d6d0145f |                                      | standard-store | 10511          | draft        | 
 84004999-d2cf-4af4-bfaa-c1077d1d8621 |                                      | standard-store | 10511          | sent         | 2017-05-21
 cbea0789-6886-431a-a8e1-723d5aafc7b9 |                                      | standard-store | 10511          | scheduled    | 2019-02-12
 ec8988ff-5136-4b81-b448-cd456dc487a4 |                                      | standard-store | 10511          | review       | 2019-01-13
 0e119440-5fbc-4afe-a784-a6bcfe3a6e4d |                                      | standard-store | 10511          | draft        | 
 98503a20-4396-4809-b3ec-8e330c15afa9 |                                      | standard-store | 10511          | needs_action | 2018-12-11
 d33a9173-dc64-464f-8e58-49b4c9c2fdae |                                      | standard-store | 10511          | draft        | 
 bee0dc72-acca-44e2-82ea-d18e830f91a2 |                                      | standard-store | 10511          | sent         | 2016-03-12
```

So the output will be like

```
                  id                  |            collection_id             |      type      | affiliation_id |    status    | scheduled_for_date 
--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+----------------+----------------+--------------+--------------------
 1143c066-01ed-4eb5-a146-68487de702a9 | bce85e31-4d2f-43b1-b263-57fca356856f | multi-store    | 12091          | draft        | 
 6e4dee09-7a4e-47be-bdd8-935a67bb2063 | 740f6b42-bbf1-4aeb-8fe9-6874635d9e29 | multi-store    | 12091          | draft        | 
 3bb38fbd-d411-4f78-9c42-c858bf57b784 |                                      | standard-store | 10511          | draft        | 
 fbb3b175-1a3b-4515-b0b3-0ce6d6d0145f |                                      | standard-store | 10511          | draft        | 
 84004999-d2cf-4af4-bfaa-c1077d1d8621 |                                      | standard-store | 10511          | sent         | 2017-05-21
 cbea0789-6886-431a-a8e1-723d5aafc7b9 |                                      | standard-store | 10511          | scheduled    | 2019-02-12
 ec8988ff-5136-4b81-b448-cd456dc487a4 |                                      | standard-store | 10511          | review       | 2019-01-13
 0e119440-5fbc-4afe-a784-a6bcfe3a6e4d |                                      | standard-store | 10511          | draft        | 
 98503a20-4396-4809-b3ec-8e330c15afa9 |                                      | standard-store | 10511          | needs_action | 2018-12-11
 d33a9173-dc64-464f-8e58-49b4c9c2fdae |                                      | standard-store | 10511          | draft        | 
 bee0dc72-acca-44e2-82ea-d18e830f91a2 |                                      | standard-store | 10511          | sent         | 2016-03-12
```

One way to do it is by `union`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (collection_id)
    collection_id,
    id,
    type,
    affiliation_id,
    status,
    scheduled_for_date
from
    message
where
    type = 'multi-store'

union

SELECT
    collection_id,
    id,
    type,
    affiliation_id,
    status,
    scheduled_for_date
from
    message
where
    type = 'standard-store'
```

But I feel that's less efficient, another option could be case based grouping. But that includes complexity when need to add all the select fields to group.

What is the most efficient way to write the query?

Comment: I would think a union query would be pretty efficient if you have an index on the `type` column, and potentially a composite index on `collection_id, type`.

Comment: There's nothing inferently "inefficient" about `UNION` queries - it's just a way of describing a query that returns disjoint sets, which you _could_ also do with the `OR` operator. i.e. `SELECT a FROM b WHERE c = 1 UNION SELECT a FROM b WHERE c = 2` is _equivalent and identical_ to `SELECT a FROM b WHERE c = 1 OR c = 2`.

Comment: You can have a `CASE` expression in the `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: Essential, missing info: Roughly how many rows total? What percentage of rows is "multi-store"? Roughly how many duplicates on avg. per distinct `collection_id` among those? Your version of Postgres? Consider [instructions for \[postgresql-performance\] questions](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info). Also, define "first" in group of duplicates precisely.

Comment: So do you have your answer? Or are you going to add more information?

Answer (score 1):

The best solution depends on undisclosed cardinalities.

Assuming relatively *few*  "multi-store" rows, and relatively *few* rows per distinct `collection_id` among those, your `UNION` query looks good - after a couple of tweaks:

```sql
(  -- parentheses required
SELECT DISTINCT ON (collection_id)
       id, collection_id, type, affiliation_id, status, scheduled_for_date
FROM   message
WHERE  type = 'multi-store'
ORDER  BY collection_id, affiliation_id  -- ! to pick row with min affiliation_id
)
   
UNION ALL  -- !!!
SELECT id, collection_id, type, affiliation_id, status, scheduled_for_date
FROM   message
WHERE  type = 'standard-store';
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/NhUlST7A)

Use `UNION ALL`. Just `UNION` tries to eliminate (non-existent) duplicates, adding pointless cost.

Typically, you want a deterministic, stable pick from each set with the same `collection_id`. Add a suitable `ORDER BY` clause accordingly. See:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

In this case, a [partial index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-partial.html) would be of help:

```
CREATE INDEX ON message (collection_id, affiliation_id) WHERE type = 'multi-store';
```

The index is used for the small share of "multi-store" rows, the rest is read from a sequential scan.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `distinct on` clause with a `case` expression.

```
select distinct on (case when type='multi-store' then collection_id else id end)
  id, collection_id, type,
  affiliation_id, status, scheduled_for_date 
from the_table;
```

DB-Fiddle [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rFqufV5t2Lxjc5Nxk8Q1CW/0)

Or, assuming that `collection_id` is NULL for types other than 'multi-store', even simpler

```sql
select distinct on (coalesce(collection_id, id)) ...
```